# Trigger on Read Only Secondary Always On Availability Groups Replica

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, alwayson

Does anyone know if it is possible to create a `Trigger` on a `Read Only Secondary Always On Availability Groups Replica` in `Microsoft SQL Server 2012`?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible; the database is read-only and creating a trigger would require a write to system tables to record the trigger's creation.